# Disable :hover when a certain class is set

Tags: jquery

I was wondering wether it is possible to disable the css `:hover` function via Jquery when a class, e.g. `.active` is set to an element.

Reason for this is a navigation, in which the certain link will be marked as clicked via `.addClass('active')` - function. When I hover over this certain element, it will get a border of 4px as my `:hover`-function looks like this:

```
nav ul li a:hover {
   border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give css like this

```
nav ul li a.active:hover{
   border-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: almost! It removes the border when hovering. Changed it to this: `#nav ul li a:hover {   }`, and now it works

Answer (score 0):

You could always just change the hover functionality for the element directly in css:

```
nav ul li a.active:hover {
     border-bottom: none;
}
```